# Cancel all scope children coroutines based on any child result

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

Assume there are two suspend function which return a boolean. They need to be launched in parallel but cancel each other if `false` is returned.

```
suspend fun task1(): Boolean {
    delay(10000)
    return true
}
suspend fun task2(): Boolean {
    return false
}
```

The tasks can be run in parallel by launching them with `async` and cancel each other by throwing `CancellationException` inside a `coroutineScope` as shown below.

```
coroutineScope {
    setOf(
        async { task1() },
        async { task2() }
    ).forEach{ d ->
        d.await().also {
            if (it == false)
                throw CancellationException()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the results are processed in the order of `await` calls, i.e. `task2` result is processed only after `task1` result and hence `task2` won't ever cancel `task1`.
It is possible to re-arrange this to let `task2` cancel `task1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to wait for more results at once in a parallel manner (instead of the sequential manner where your problem lies) you can use the [`select`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.selects/select.html) clause, like this:

```kt
coroutineScope {
        val tasks = setOf(
                async { task1() },
                async { task2() }
        )
        
        select {
            tasks.forEach {
                it.onAwait { finishedSuccessfully ->
                    if (!finishedSuccessfully)
                        tasks.forEach { task -> task.cancel() }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works. The only modification I've done was to wrap `coroutineScope` into try/catch and replace `tasks.forEach { task -> task.cancel() }` with `throw CancellationException()`. Otherwise any code after `select` would get executed after tasks are cancelled. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mutableStateFlow` and listen if any data changes then collect it and cancel all tasks if it returns false. Like in LiveData.